# Composing scalaz io effect objects

Tags: scala, scalaz, io-monad

I'm trying to use scalaz's ioeffect IO[E,A] monad for a piece of code that is very effectful.

The code I'm trying to rewrite with IO[E,A] at a high level takes some metadata about a file that's store in a cloud. The code attempts to:

1. download the file
2. extract strings from the file
3. build a pojo that contains the file text contents
4. submits the pojo to some queue/restful service

The details of the steps aren't that important, but what I was thinking of doing was to do something along the lines of:

```
def processShareActivity(fileObject: FileObject): IO[ProcessFileFailure, IndexResponse] = {
    for {
        file <- downloadFile (fileObject)
        text <- extractText (file)
        searchFileObject <- IO.point(buildSearchFileObject (fileObject, file, text))
        indexedResponse <- indexSearchFileObject (searchFileObject)
    } yield indexedResponse
}

def indexSearchFileObject(fileObject: SearchFileObject): IO[IndexFailure, IndexResponse] = ???

def buildSearchFileObject(fileObject: FileObject, file: File, str: String): SearchFileObject = ???

def extractText(file: File): IO[ExtractionFailure, String] = ???

def downloadFile(fileObject: FileObject): IO[DownloadFileFailure, File] = ???
```

The problem is that an instance of `IO[E,A]` and `IO[F,B]` do not seem to compose. That is, since for example `downloadFile`'s IO signature returns `DownloadFileFailure` for its error scenario and `extractText` returns `ExtractionFailure`, those monads can't seem to compose in the `for` comprehension.

Is there an easy way for my top level `for` comprehension to compose such that it results in a `IO[ProcessFileFailure, IndexResponse]` where `ProcessFileFailure` is some kind of a wrapping failure object around the different kind of failures that can happen in the submethods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you do need a way to unify these errors into a common one:

for example:

```
sealed trait ProcessFileFailure
object ProcessFileFailure {
   case class Index(e: IndexFailure) extends ProcessFileFailure
   case class Extraction(e: ExtractionFailure) extends ProcessFileFailure
   case class Download(e: DownloadFileFailure) extends ProcessFileFailure
}
```

And your for-comprehension will become:

```
for {
        file <- downloadFile (fileObject).leftMap(ProcessFileFailure.Download)
        text <- extractText (file).leftMap(ProcessFileFailure.Extraction)
        searchFileObject <- IO.point(buildSearchFileObject (fileObject, file, text))
        indexedResponse <- indexSearchFileObject (searchFileObject).leftMap(ProcessFileFailure.Index)
    } yield indexedResponse
```

Its awkward, but it does have the advantage of being able to store everything that went wrong and exactly the context in which it happened.